# Vanishing locus of a section

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $F$ be a rank $2$ locally free sheaf on a smooth complex projective surface $X$. Assume that it has non-trivial sections. Let $D$ be a fixed divisor on $X$. Then consider the following set:

$F_D:=\{s \in H^0(F)| D  \space \text{is the maximal divisor along which s vanishes}\}$.

Is it known that whether the projectivization $F_D$ is open or closed (or locally closed) in $\mathbb P(H^0(F))$?

Any input is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is locally closed. More precisely, it is open in the projective subspace
$$
\mathbb{P}(H^0(F(-D))) \subset \mathbb{P}(H^0(F)).
$$

Comment: thank you very much for the answer. I have one further question : If we instead consider the pairs $\{(F,s)| s \in H^0(F), D  \space \text{is the maximal divisor along which s vanishes}\}$ inside $A \times \mathbb P(H^0(F))$ ($A$ appropriate closed subspace of moduli space of stable bundles), then is the local closedness property stays?

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by $A \times \mathbb{P}(H^0(F))$ since the space of global sections of a vector bundle varying in a moduli space is not constant.

Comment: I wrote the description wrong. I meant $\{(F,s)| F \in A, s \in \mathbb P(H^0(F)), D  \space \text{is the maximal divisor along which s vanishes}\}$ inside $\{(F,s)| F \in A, s \in \mathbb P(H^0(F))\}$ locally closed? (Please let me know if this is still confusing)

Comment: To make sense of the question you should explain how do you endow the set $\{(F,s) \mid F \in A, s \in \mathbb{P}(H^0(F))\}$ with a structure of algebraic variety (or at least with a topology).

Comment: a detailed description can be found in https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/10.1142/S0129167X11007045 Page-798, second paragraph.